# Partial Function of T to T for any T

Tags: scala

I've been asking a lot of questions about Partial Functions today. Earlier I wanted to do something like this,

```
def partial : PartialFunction[T, T]
```

Where what I am trying to say is that, whatever type you give me, if I'm defined, I'll give you the same type back. Obviously that above syntax is nonsense but it gives you the idea of what I am trying to do.

So that when people are implementing this, they are forced to do

```
{
case s : String = > s + "hello"
case i : Int => i + 100
}
```

And can't do

```
{
case s : String => 4
case i : Int = "hello"
}
```

I don't believe this is possible. Perhaps I am missing something very simple, and upvotes await those who can show me the light.

Answer (score 2):

You can *kind of* do it, depending on your use case:

```
type PartialT[T] = PartialFunction[T,T]
def something(pfn: PartialT[String]) = println("yarp")

something { case s: String => 42 }
  <console>:10: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Int(42)
   required: String
          something { case s: String => 42 }
                                        ^

something { case s: String => "xxx" }
  yarp
```

Comment: Was seeing if there was a way to do it across multiple types. The polymorphic functions in Shapeless looks interesting, been looking for a reason to checkout Shapeless for a while, and I guess this is the time :)